# Why does my database object show no Recordsets?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Why does my database object show no Recordsets?  And why does it not show a Connection?  The key bit of code is:

```
Public Sub PrintRecords()
  Dim dbCurr As DAO.Database
  Set dbCurr = CurrentDb

  Dim rsCourses as Recordset
  Set rsCourses = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(“Courses”)
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot at time of error]
Here is my screenshot, where the database has tables (upper left), but the CurrentDB object has a name but no Recordsets (in the locals window below.)

For what it’s worth, this is in Access 2013, following [this](https://fisher.osu.edu/~muhanna.1/837/MSAccess/tutorials/dao_intr.pdf) tutorial to manipulate the database, stopping on the error “Run-time error ‘3078’:  The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query”.  But the problem seems to be deeper than that.

Comment: You don't have any recordsets open yet because your debug line is on the OpenRecordset method - nothing has been opened yet. Other than that - fix your double quotes like @Andre points out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typographic quotes in there, use straight ones "".

And use your assigned database object:

```
Set rsCourses = dbCurr.OpenRecordset("Courses")
```

And *please* don't post only screenshots of code, copy & paste the code itself as text.

Comment: Thanks -- changing the quotes worked.  Curiously the troublesome typographic quotes were in the tutorial.

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunate. The tutorial is a PDF that was probably created from Word, and Word automatically replaces the quotes unless this feature is disabled. @MattF.